# BGE: Create a single mesh

Tags: mesh, game-engine, makehuman

Can I create a single mesh character from multiple meshes from the following file?

All off that in a single Body, obj, mesh.

[image: Screen]

[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32957)

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this makehuman file?

Comment: I've updated the question!

Comment: You can join meshes by selecting them and pressing [Ctrl]+[J], but i am not sure if the animated parts will behave correctly afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Select all the meshes: (hold SHIFT while clicking them one by one)
[image: Select]
Press CTRL+J:
[image: Joined]
I haven't done any extensive checking on the rigging, but the character still walks:
[image: Walking]

Comment: I've done the same thing but is mesh over mesh, is there another solution to make it a single clear mesh?

Comment: When you join meshes with Ctrl+J, they will remain in their original relative positions, and no vertices will be removed. I tried removing doubles (in Edit mode, select all, then Crtl+V --> D), and it seems the character still behaves as expected. Though this may leave some interior vertices. You may also try the Boolean modifier in union mode, but that will most likely mess up the vertex groups. In 2.72, there's an intersect function that might do the trick, but I'm on 2.71, so I can't test it.

Comment: Thank you helped me a lot. I can delete the vertices that I don't need before joining.